# Typescript,testing Api calls in Redux actions, mocking class in Enzyme, Jest

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, react-redux, jestjs

I have an issue where I need to be mocking a class `Api` that is called within my redux actions, this class calls axios get, post etc... which need to be mocked.  I have been following [this](https://wanago.io/2018/09/17/javascript-testing-tutorial-part-four-mocking-api-calls-and-simulating-react-components-interactions/) tutorial explaining how to mock axios and [this](https://medium.com/codeclan/mocking-es-and-commonjs-modules-with-jest-mock-37bbb552da43) tutorial about how to mock a class but neither approaches appear to be working.

Now for some code... here's an example of the type of action I need to test.

```
export const getAlldata = (id: string) => {
    return (dispatch: any) => {
        dispatch(beginAjaxRequest(id, types.BEGIN_GET_DATA_AJAX));
        return Api.get("/data/data").then((response: any) => {
            dispatch(getDataSuccess(response.data, id))
        }).catch((error) => {
            dispatch(handleAjaxError(id, new Alert({ id: id, title: "Error getting data", message: error.toString(), timestamp: Date.now(), error: true })));
        });
    }
}
```

and the parts of `Api` this calls.

```
import axios from 'axios';

class Api {
    static get(path: string) {
        return axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: (global as any).apiDomain + path,
            headers: {
                Authorization: "Bearer " + (global as any).authentication.getToken(),
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        });
    }
}

export default Api;
```

Which I have tried to mock in src/mocks/Api (two underscores following and preceding mocks)

```
import * as Promise from 'bluebird';
import { getTestData } from '../models/_tests/TestData';

class Api {
    static get(path: string) {
        switch (path) {
            case "/data/data":
                return Promise.resolve({
                    data: getTestData(3)
                });
            default:
                return {};
        }
    }
}

export default Api;
```

and setup in my setupTests.

```
import * as Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import Api from './__mocks__/Api';
const Adapter = require("enzyme-adapter-react-16");

(global as any).Api = Api;

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

and called in my actual test...

```
describe('thunk actions', () => {

    var middleware = [thunk];
    var mockStore = configureMockStore(middleware);
    afterAll(() => {
        cleanAll();
    });

    test('getAllData gets all data', (done: any) => {
        var store = mockStore({});
        jest.mock('../../api/Api'); // path to real Api
        var id = generateGuid();
        store.dispatch<any>((getAllData(id))).then(() => {
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

So obviously this doesn't actually test anything, I'm just trying to get this working but I keep getting errors within the real Api instead of the mock. I have also tried mocking axios but I get the same error (can't getToken of undefined) so this doesn't seem to be replacing either axios or Api, can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know you're screwed when you post a question to stackoverflow and get 0 answers and 0 responses in over a week... Not ideal but I've found a workaround to override the Api class in my thunk actions, instead of importing the Api class into all my action files and calling it directly, I now only import it into the root of my project (App.tsx) and make it global as below (stripped down to it's bare minimum).

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Api from './api/Api';

export interface State {

}

export interface Props {

}

export class App extends React.Component<Props, State> {

    state = {

    };

    componentWillMount = () => {
        (global as any).Api = Api;
    };





    public render() {
        return (
            <div>

            </div>
        );
    }
}


export default App;
```

...and then call Api on my thunk actions as below

```
export const getAlldata = (id: string) => {
    return (dispatch: any) => {
        dispatch(beginAjaxRequest(id, types.BEGIN_GET_DATA_AJAX));
        return (global as any).Api.get("/data/data").then((response: any) => {
            dispatch(getDataSuccess(response.data, id))
        }).catch((error) => {
            dispatch(handleAjaxError(id, new Alert({ id: id, title: "Error getting data", message: error.toString(), timestamp: Date.now(), error: true })));
        });
    }
}
```

Then simply override this is setupTests.ts

```
import * as Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import Api from './__mocks__/Api';
const Adapter = require("enzyme-adapter-react-16");

(global as any).Api = Api;

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

...and then there's no need for jest mocks, simply call the actions in your tests and test.

This method would also work outside of Node by replacing global with window. This does the job but is not ideal as I prefer not to use the global namespace, so if anyone knows a better way post away.